# Making vcov() accept "sigma" from an lm() object in R

Tags: r, function, regression, linear-regression, lm

`vcov()` in R gets an `lm()` object and returns the variance-covariance matrix ONLY for `Intercept` and `coefficients` (i.e., *a 2 x 2 matrix*).

I'm wondering though, how could I make `vcov()` to also add `sigma` (i.e., `summary(lm.object)$sigma)` to its operation (i.e., producing *a 3 x 3 matrix*)?

For example, if we have `m` as our `lm` object (*below*), how can we make `vcov()` compute variance-covariance matrix for `Intercept`, `coefficients` ***AND ALSO*** `sigma` from `m`?

```
q <- data.frame(bob = 1:5 - 3, jen = c(1.7, 2.6, 2.5, 4.4, 3.8) - 3)
m <- lm(bob ~ jen, q)
```

Here is what I tried without success:

```
vcov(c(m, summary(m)$sigma))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard practice is to only compute standard errors for parameters specifying the mean, not for parameters specifying the variance. Neither the `lm` function nor the `glm` function computes the quantities you're asking for.

If you really want this information, then you'll have to derive it yourself: write the log-likelihood in terms of the regression coefficients and sigma, then compute the negative of the Hessian of this function, evaluated at the maximum likelihood estimates. Invert this matrix to get the desired result.

It turns out that the answer is block diagonal, with one block for the regression coefficients and one block for `sigma`. The entry for `sigma` is `sigma^2 / (2 * n)`, where `n` is the sample size.

Example:

```
q <- data.frame(bob = 1:5 - 3, jen = c(1.7, 2.6, 2.5, 4.4, 3.8) - 3)
m <- lm(bob ~ jen, q)
p <- length(coef(m))
v <- matrix(0, p + 1, p + 1)
rownames(v) <- colnames(v) <- c(names(coef(m)), "sigma")
v[1:p, 1:p] <- vcov(m)
v[p + 1, p + 1] <- sigma(m)^2 / (2 * nobs(m))
v
#>             (Intercept)       jen      sigma
#> (Intercept)   0.1560284 0.0000000 0.00000000
#> jen           0.0000000 0.1659876 0.00000000
#> sigma         0.0000000 0.0000000 0.07801418
```